# Google Speech To Text , How to trigger the microphone(Ready To speak) to appear by shortcut key?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition

I want to use the Google Speech To Text input for my site.

How to trigger the microphone(Ready To speak) to appear by shortcut key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Ctrl+Shift+period on Windows/Linux/ChromeOS or Command+Shift+period on a Mac.

in chrome 15 or higher

Comment: Is the Ctrl+Shift+period hard coded? Is there a way to use another key combination?